# Wrap an OCaml function that receives a JS object (record)

Tags: js-of-ocaml, ocsigen

I want to write a very simple function in OCaml, and wrap it to make a JS function `jsGet` by `js_of_ocaml`, such that `jsGet` could take a JS object (or record) as input.

I tried the following code:

```
\\ in Home.js
function testJsGet () {
    var input = {field_1: 5, field_2: 6};
    var output = jsGet(input);
    document.getElementById("result").value += output;
}
```

In `wrap.ml`:

```
type t =
  < field_1: int Js.prop;
    field_2: int Js.prop
  > Js.t

let () =
  Js.Unsafe.global##.jsGet := Js.wrap_callback
      (fun (r:t) -> r##.field_1);
```

`wrap.ml` compiles well, however, running `Home.js` returns `undefined` as output.

Does anyone know how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove underscores. See Method name and underscore at http://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/2.8/manual/bindings